# Express can't load index

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I'm trying to setup my very first express web server on aws. I can get hello world to show up on port 9000 if I try to simply use "res.send" however my below code produces a error and I believe it is related to my directory structure but I can't seem to figure out the right way to write it. my server.js file is inside of a folder called home/server/server.js however my index file I am trying to load is inside of home/web/index.html. how do I write this so it loads correctly. here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + './../web/index.html')
    //res.send('Hello there, world!\n');
});

var port = 9000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port', port);
```

This is the error I currently get:

```
ForbiddenError: Forbidden
    at SendStream.error (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/send/index.js:270:31)
    at SendStream.pipe (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/send/index.js:554:12)
    at sendfile (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1099:8)
    at ServerResponse.res.sendfile (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:498:3)
    at ServerResponse.eval [as sendfile] (eval at wrapfunction (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/depd/index.js:410:22), <anonymous>:4:11)
    at /home/ubuntu/home/server/server.js:30:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ubuntu/home/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

You can use the `root` option for it:

```
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' })
```

By the way, `sendfile` is deprecated, use `sendFile`.

Comment: ah yes I see that it is deprecated. thanks! I was able to use 
    res.sendFile('/web/index.html', { root: '.' }) and that worked! thank you!